# Can't find the problem with my solution to leetcode problem

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying the ransom note challenge:

Given two strings ransomNote and magazine, return true if ransomNote can be constructed by using the letters from magazine and false otherwise.

Each letter in magazine can only be used once in ransomNote.

Example 1:

Input: ransomNote = "a", magazine = "b"
Output: false
Example 2:

Input: ransomNote = "aa", magazine = "ab"
Output: false
Example 3:

Input: ransomNote = "aa", magazine = "aab"
Output: true

here is my solution:

```
public static boolean canConstruct(String ransomNote, String magazine) {
        ArrayList<Character> ransomChar = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> magazineChar = new ArrayList<Character>();

        if (ransomNote.length() == 1 && magazine.length() == 1) {
            if (ransomNote.equals(magazine)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        else if (ransomNote.length() == 1 && magazine.length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < magazine.length(); i++) {
                if (magazine.charAt(i) == ransomNote.charAt(0)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        else if (ransomNote.length() > 1 && magazine.length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ransomNote.length(); i++) {
                ransomChar.add(ransomNote.charAt(i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < magazine.length(); i++) {
                magazineChar.add(magazine.charAt(i));
            }
            while (ransomChar.size() > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ransomChar.size(); i++) {
                    boolean flag = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < magazineChar.size(); j++) {
                        if (ransomChar.get(i).equals(magazineChar.get(j))) {
                            ransomChar.remove(i);
                            magazineChar.remove(j);
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        else if (ransomChar.isEmpty()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (ransomChar.size() == 1 && magazineChar.size() == 1) {
                if (ransomChar.equals(magazineChar)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            else if (ransomChar.size() == 1 && magazineChar.size() > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < magazineChar.size(); i++) {
                    if (ransomChar.get(0).equals(magazineChar.get(i))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am passing most test cases but it throws an error at input:

```
    "bg"
    "efjbdfbdgfjhhaiigfhbaejahgfbbgbjagbddfgdiaigdadhcfcj"
```

It throws error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at line: if (ransomChar.get(i).equals(magazineChar.get(j)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What error is it throwing?  Please put the error in your question, including the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry about that I just updated it.

Comment: You are trying to extract the first character from an empty String and Java is complaining that this is not allowed. . Best to run the code using your IDE's debug mode to see why this is happening

Comment: You are removing items from lists that you are iterating over.  This is generally a bad idea, and is going to screw up your logic.  When you remove an item from a list, all items after that shift down one slot.  But you increment the loop index anyway.  At best, you're skipping characters you should be considering, and worse, you're going to crash like you're seeing.  You need to rethink how your loops work to allow for the fact that your removing items shifts other items down.

Comment: You might want to consider using the StringBuffer class.  It would clean up your code and avoid having to explicitly copy your input strings character by character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to attack your problem by building a set of candidate characters from `magazine`.  Once you've done that, you just iterate over the `ransomNote`, checking the set for each character.  If you find it, you remove it from the set.  If you don't, then you return `false`.  If you make it all the way through, you return `true`.  You need to use a `MultiSet` because you need to be able to represent multiple copies of the same character in the magazine.

Here's how to do that:

```
public static boolean canConstruct(String ransomNote, String magazine) {
    MultiSet<Character> magazineChars = new HashMultiSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < magazine.length(); i++)
        magazineChars.add(magazine.charAt(i));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ransomNote.length(); i++) {
        Character c = ransomNote.charAt(i);
        if (magazineChars.contains(c))
            magazineChars.remove(c);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using Guava's `MultiSet` is a very interesting idea (*though not sure if LeetCode supports this library*). In the similar way, it can be achieved using a standard `Map<Character,Integer>`. To generate a histogram, we can use `merge(magazine.charAt(i),1,Integer::sum)`. And to verify whether it's possible to contract the given `String`, a contains check with `coupute(c, (k,v) -> v == 1 ? null : v - 1)` (or old good `put` + get`).

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of this loop:

> ```
>                 for (int i = 0; i < ransomChar.size(); i++) {
>                     boolean flag = false;
>                     for (int j = 0; j < magazineChar.size(); j++) {
>                         if (ransomChar.get(i).equals(magazineChar.get(j))) {
>                             ransomChar.remove(i);
>                             magazineChar.remove(j);
>                             flag = true;
>                         }
>                         else if (ransomChar.isEmpty()) {
>                             return true;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     if (!flag) {
>                         return false;
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

, you know that `i` is *initially* less than `ransomChar.size()`, so that it is safe to perform `ransomChar.get(i)`.

However, the inner loop may remove one (or more!) elements of `ransomChar`, after which it may no longer be true that `i` is less than `ransomChar.size()`.  The inner loop continues to iterate, and as a result, it can attempt to retrieve an element of `ransomChar` that does not exist.

Honestly, the code overall is a mess.  Other than this specific issue,

- I see no need why you need special cases for all the variations on sizes of note and magazine.  I think you might write better code for this if you devoted some effort to designing an approach that just works correctly for all cases.
- you are not making good use of the available features of the classes you are using
- you are not making good use of general Java language features that would be applicable.

For example, I might write that particular loop as:

```
                for (Character c : ransomChar) {
                    if (!magazineChar.remove(c)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
```

---

And that's before we come to the fact that you've chosen a suboptimal algorithm.  Its execution time will scale as note size * magazine size, whereas there are alternatives that will scale as note size + magazine size, instead.  That may in fact be important, because choice of an efficient algorithm is one thing that the test cases for coding challenges such as this often try to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Please find small and simple solution with Time complexity O(n) and Space complexity O(256) or O(1)

```
 int[] count = new int[256];
        for (char c : magazine.toCharArray()) {
            count[c]++;
        }
        for (char c : ransomNote.toCharArray()) {
            if (count[c]-- == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Harsh so you are trying to access the element of ransomChar which do not even exists. look at the lines

```java
if (ransomChar.get(i).equals(magazineChar.get(j))) {
    ransomChar.remove(i);
    magazineChar.remove(j);
    flag = true;
}
```

you are removing the elements from the lists and and every time you remove the elements from the list their indexing changes and and when it rechecks the condition the list is already empty after several iteration. Hence giving the run time error. to avoid this you should check whether the list is empty or not , first (you are checking it after).